# Tensorflow sigmoid regression stays linear

Tags: python, tensorflow, non-linear-regression

I'm trying to make a simple neural net fit a simple function using tensor flow, I know that the structure and parameters I'm using work as I've achieved this in MatLab, but I need to port this over to another language (currently Python, but later c++). As such I'm trying to find a good neural network library, I thought that would be TensorFlow, but it's proving very finicky. Here are the important bits of the code

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f1 = lambda x: ((x < .5) * np.power(x, 2) + (x > .5) * x) * 2 -1
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 180).reshape(-1,1)
y = f1(x).reshape(-1, 1)
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid, input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.keras.activations.linear))
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error, optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(0.001), metrics=[tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error])
model.fit(x, y, batch_size=1, epochs=3)
xtest = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100).reshape(-1, 1)
ytest = model.predict(xtest)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(xtest, ytest)
plt.show()
```

This when the expected plot and predictions are plotted it results in
[This Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPh8A.png) where the dots are the expected function and the solid line is the prediction
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The network has to be a layer of 100 sigmoid activated neurons followed by a linear output layer, even if I change the number of epochs and batch sizes the network still trains linear. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you show your working Matlab solution for comparison?

Answer (score 1):

You may try changing activation and increasing training time, I changed optimizer to `Adam`, increased training epochs to 30 and got this result.
[image: result image]

Code :

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f1 = lambda x: ((x < .5) * np.power(x, 2) + (x > .5) * x) * 2 -1
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 180).reshape(-1,1)
y = f1(x).reshape(-1, 1)
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid, input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.keras.activations.linear))
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error, 
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01), 
              metrics=[tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error])
model.fit(x, y, batch_size=1, epochs=30)
xtest = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100).reshape(-1, 1)
ytest = model.predict(xtest)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(xtest, ytest)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I need to use sigmoid, relu won't work for what I need to do with the model after training. I known that using sigmoid and training using 3 epochs (l-m backpropagation) works from matlab, I'm just so confused as to why the model is staying linear.

Comment: If I understood correctly, l-m backpropagation updates weights differently as compared to backpropagation in tensorflow which I found [here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/trainlm.html). I found using adam with sigmoid works fine. I am updating results in answer.